# Headers compiling faster?

Tags: c, header, compiler-construction

I wanted to go more in depth to why using headers and after some research I've found some convicing answer but in most responses people say that it makes compilation faster, but all those answers are vague and don't say exactly how headers make compiling easier.
Can someone please go more in depth into the subject?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing project into headers doesn't increase the compilation speed if you are compiling from the scratch.

However they make modifiying the code a lot faster. The compilation of a project normally goes like this. First you compile each file into a machine code that has relative addresses(so the code's start address is not known). Then you link all of the other files to create your project.

Imagine you have a project that has 10.000 files. If you change 1 file only, when building the project only that file will be compiled then all of the other files will be linked. If you haven't divided the project to 10.000 files, when building a simple change you would have to compile all other 10.000 files. So once you compile the project, debugging get quite faster with this approach.

Also, compiling a file is a single threaded program. So you can paralelize the compilation speed by compiling several files together. `-j` flag for the `make` command does this.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about compilation speed. The issue is software maintainability.

Headers are meant to contain stuff that is needed at compile time by different sources, typically #define constants and function declarations that makeup an API.

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers (actually just MSVC) can take good advantage from using precompiled headers. That effectively means if you have the same include file at the begin of each compilation unit, then you can tell the compiler to process that just once, and for each other compilation unit only start processing right after that include.

If you see projects with an `stdafx.h` header which is pulling in a lot of other headers commonly used throughout the project, then it is just that.

Other compilers like gcc or clang are much faster at processing the source code, so there is no gain to be made from caching such an incomplete representation yet.

---

Aside from precompiled headers, they also serve as a common interface between compilation units. When talking about C++ with templates, or C with excessive code generation by templates, then it occasionally makes a difference to limit visibility of the resulting symbols only to that specific compilation unit during compilation phase. For limiting visibility during the following link phase, `static` keyword is the one to use.

Realistically this isn't affecting most projects though. In fact, for smaller projects a common technique is actually to concat all compilation units just before compiling, so that separation is eliminated at compile time, without a dedicated link step. Given no conflicts in static symbols from the merged compilation units, that actually tends to save a lot more compilation time than the strict use of minimal interfaces in the header.

Estimate from practical experience is that you need to start reducing visibility for compiler performance reasons once you get above 50-100k symbols visible in a single compilation unit.